# No activity found to handle geo intent in emulator

Tags: android, android-intent, geo

I have following simple method in my main activity.

```
    private void showMap(String name ) {
        String thePlace = name.replaceAll(" ", "+");
        Intent intent= new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q=" + thePlace+ "" ));
        startActivity(intent);  
    }
```

And in my manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But when I run the app in emulator, it crashed and according to Log, it says

```
  No activity found to handle the intent
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is geolocation enabled in emulator settings?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the Maps app isn't installed on the emulator, so the message that it's giving you pretty much explains the problem. There isn't anything setup on the emulator to handle that kind of intent...